# Positive integral everywhere implies positive function a.e

Tags: integration, measure-theory, inequality

I would like to get feedback on my demonstration of this simple statement :

Let $f$ be an integrable function on the measure space $(X,S,\mu)$.

\begin{align}
\text{If }\int_E f \, d\mu \geq 0\text{ for all }E\in S\text{ then }f \geq 0\text{ a.e.}
\end{align}

I came up with this and I'm not sure about the reasoning ...

Let $D = \{x: f(x)<0\}$ be the set where $f$ is negative. Since $f$ is integrable we have :
$$\int_Df < \int_D 0 = 0$$
But for all $E\in S$ we have $\int_E f\geq 0$. So by taking $E=D$ we have :
$$0 \leq \int_Df < 0. $$ Which is impossible. So the set $D$ must not be measurable.

I would think that I have to find a way to show that $\mu(D) = 0$ to conclude that $f \geq 0$ a.e

Thanks for any help !

Comment: it suffices to show that D is measurable

Comment: Actually, $D$ is measurable but the trouble is that $f\lt0$ on $A$ implies that $\displaystyle\int_Af\mathrm d\mu\lt0$ **only when** $\mu(A)\ne0$.

Answer (score 5):

I think it much more convincing to note that $\{f < 0\} = \cup_{n=1}^\infty \{f \leq -n^{-1}\}$. Suppose that $\alpha_n = \mu(\{f \leq -n^{-1}\}) > 0$ for some $n \geq 1$; then $$\int_{\{f \leq -n^{-1}\}} f d\mu \leq -n^{-1}\alpha_n < 0,$$
a contradiction to the hypothesis since $f^{-1}(-\infty,-n^{-1})$ is the pre-image of a Borel set, hence measurable. Thus $\alpha_n = 0$ for all $n \geq 1$, and $$\mu(\{f < 0\}) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_n = 0.$$

Comment: Interesting !Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

$D$ is certainly measurable. Just replace your strict inequality with $\leq$, and you are good to go.

Comment: Where is the flaw in my reasoning ?

EDIT: Oh I got it, we can add $\int_0^0f$ which will give us a $\leq$ type of inequality. But then where do I go from there ?

Comment: @user149705 since we have $\int_D f = 0$ then what can we deduce about $f/D$?

Comment: I think $f = 0$ a.e ?

Comment: @user149705 or $\mu(D) = 0$

Comment: So if $f=0$ a.e we could have $\mu(D) > 0$ and the result wouldn't hold ?

Comment: $D$ is measurable because it is the inverse image of a measurable subset of the line.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$
D = \{ x \mid f(x) < 0 \} = f^{-1}([-\infty,0))
$$
Thus what can we say about $D$?

From here consider your hypothesis you should get that either $\mu(D) = 0$ or $f = 0$ a.e., and so the conclusion follows.

**Note:** If we have $f = 0$ a.e. then we have $\mu(\{x \in D \mid f(x) \neq 0 \}) = 0$ so we must have $\mu(D) = 0$ thus leading to the hypothesis again. Note that $\{x \in D \mid f(x) \neq 0 \} = D$ since $D = \{ x \mid f(x) < 0 \}$.

Comment: I guess the part I don't get is this :

$\int_D f=0 \implies f=0$ a.e or $\implies \mu(D) = 0$

For the first possibility $f=0$ a.e on the set $D$ and not $S$ right ? Meaning, there exist a set $P\subset D$ with $\mu(P) = 0$. which doesn't lead to the right conclusion. Or Am I missing something ?

EDIT: Got it ! Thanks !

Comment: @user149705 check out my note again, I tried to clear that up. If $f = 0$ almost everywhere then the set of $x \in D$ for which f doesn't equal zero is equal $0$, and then note that the definition of $D$ is so that every element has this property.

Comment: @user149705 glad to help, I just tried to expand on my comment above (on Chris' post)